# chef run_list remove all recipes

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Is there a way to remove all the recipes in the run_list of a node?

I have a problem statement where I need to remove all in the run_list and add it at runtime whenever required.

I can remove each individually, but I am dealing with a lot of nodes at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Look up `knife exec` and the `transform` helper. Something like `knife exec -E 'transform("*:*") {|n| n.run_list.reset! }`